# American option - Upper bound

Tags: monte-carlo, american-options

I have computed a lower bound for an american option through longstaff and schwartz's algorithm. Now I have to compute the upper bound as andersen and broadie does in their article [linked](http://www.columbia.edu/~mnb2/broadie/Assets/primal_dual_ms_2004.pdf). Can anybody help me with a small numerical example? I only have the procedure from the article, which is hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

there is a C++ implemented version in the gold part of the Kooderive open source project.

Comment: Link to GitHub?

Comment: googling kooderive ought to do. Kooderive.sourceforge.net

Comment: Go to https://sourceforge.net/projects/kooderive . Do  "Browse all files". You will find Andersen_Broadie_gold.cpp in the gold subdirectory of the latest release